# Get back deleted question

Tags: feature-request, questions, deleted-questions

Deleted questions aren't listed on your questions page - before shutting down your browser, you can still "undelete it".  After shutting down though, the page is lost - is there a way to access them?

Comment: Earn enough reputation, they seem to be visible to moderators.

Comment: @Ralph, you need 10k to view deleted questions, which means it's out of reach of most casual users, at least, in the near future.

Comment: So true, but the only way at the moment.

Comment: It's also important to bookmark the page you'll (eventually) want to undelete, as it's very difficult to find a deleted question you're looking for.

Comment: @Kyle: Marc Gravell says that moderators can see deleted questions in the user's profile. I don't have any deleted questions for you to test on, but you could check Jon Skeet's Meta profile and see if he has one.

Comment: @mmyers: That's true - I was speaking more towards people that get 10k rep being able to see their deleted questions again.